# Sitefinity upgrade from 3.6 to 8.0 or 9.0

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-5, sitefinity-8

I want to upgrade from sitefinity 3.6 to 8.0 or higher for a production server.So would like to know the known issue can come for upgradation. we do have custom controls also. any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct path for upgrading from 3.6 to 8. First you need to upgrade to 3.7 and then follow this article:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/migrate-sitefinity-3-7-projects

Comment: do i have to recreate RAd or custom modules or can just rebuild them under new version. how complex is that process and also is there any impact on the themes which are currently being used, which are using old css and scripts.

Comment: The API of the v.4+ is much different from the API of 3.x so you would probably need to change all custom modules. Same applies to the themes as well.

Comment: change means need to recreate or rebuild.

Comment: It means you will need to change the code and rebuild, yes.